# facebook graph api returning different response to the same request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I came across to what I think is a weird behavior of the graph api..

From the facebook reference page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ 
, I tried the newsfeed method https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...

and get the following json response:

```
{
"data": [
]
}
```

but than clicking on refresh button I get a feed:

and this is happening randomly at every refresh.. some of them with data in response some of them empty..

Looks like fb servers are out of sync.. and it depends which one you hit..

is this happened to someone else?

thanks.

Comment: I think this question belongs here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewforum.php?id=52

Comment: @AlienWebguy that forum seems to be deprecated in favor of using SO, so them posting programming related questions is OK here, however, this particular question is more of a bug that should be logged with Facebook at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

I looked here: https://developers.facebook.com/live_status  and it appears there is some issues but not anything related to what you're saying.  I remember there was another question over the weekend from someone saying they were getting back different results from the same query, but I cannot remember what it is.   @John, it sounds like the issue is reproducible, so you should file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs